# How to make the loop faster?

Tags: r, loops

My code looks as below, I am wondering if there any better way to make it faster:

```
pos=NULL
row=data.frame(matrix(nrow=216,ncol=4))
colnames(row)=c("sub","subi","group","trial")
for (i in 1:100000){
  row$sub="Positive"
  row$subi=NA
  row$group=NA
  row$subi[1:144]=c(1:144)
  row$group[1:144]=1
  row$subi[145:216]=c(1:72)
  row$group[145:216]=2
  row$trial=i
  pos=rbind(pos,row)
}
```

Comment: Well yes, the for loop isn't doing anything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing different in each pass of the loop is `trial`. `rep` is your friend. For the other columns, R will automatically recycle to match the longest column (here, it is `trial` with 21.6M rows).

```
pos <- data.frame(
  sub = "Positive",
  subi = c(1:144, 1:72),
  group = rep.int(1:2, c(144, 72)),
  trial = rep(1:1e5, each = 216)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed. You can build a `data.frame` or `tibble`(my example) on your own.

Given you want to adjust the row length later:

```r
library(dplyr)

n_rows <- 10000

tibble(
  trail = 1:n_rows,
  sub = "positive",
  subi = c(seq(1:144), seq(1:72), rep(NA, n_rows-216)),     
  group = c(rep(1, 144), rep(2, 72), rep(NA, n_rows-216))
  )
```

Output is:

```
# A tibble: 10,000 × 4
   trail sub       subi group
   <int> <chr>    <int> <dbl>
 1     1 positive     1     1
 2     2 positive     2     1
 3     3 positive     3     1
 4     4 positive     4     1
 5     5 positive     5     1
 6     6 positive     6     1
 7     7 positive     7     1
 8     8 positive     8     1
 9     9 positive     9     1
10    10 positive    10     1
# … with 9,990 more rows
```

Comment: you don't need `mutate()` here, everything can go into the `tibble()` call

Comment: yes true, had another first approach, that didn't work out. Ty

Comment: This was my original idea as well.  However, OP asked for a *faster* solution and my testing using `microbenchmark`, indicated that this approach was *on average* slower than OP's solution, because of a small number of very slow iterations.  Hence I didn't post.  What does your testing show?

Comment: Also, I think you have misinterpreted OP's intent.  OP appears to be replicating a 216 row data frame once for each value of `trail` (sic), giving a 216,000 row data frame.  Note the call to `rbind()` on the final line of the loop.  Your solution appears to give a 10000 row data frame.

Comment: right, we should ask for an expected outcome of his/her loop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to replicate this data frame 100,000 times, with each iteration of the frame having a different `trial` number.

```
data.frame(sub = rep("Positive", 216), 
           subi = c(1:144, 1:72), 
           group = rep(c(1, 2), c(144, 72)))
```

The `replicate` function is great for running static code multiple time.  So one option is to create your 100,000 copies and then update the trial number.

```
FrameList <- 
  replicate(n = 100, 
            {
              data.frame(sub = rep("Positive", 216), 
                         subi = c(1:144, 1:72), 
                         group = rep(c(1, 2), c(144, 72)), 
                         trial = rep(NA_real_, 216))
            }, 
            simplify = FALSE)
```

To update the trial number, you can go with a `for` loop

```
for (i in seq_along(FrameList)){
  FrameList$trial <- i
}
```

or you can try something fancy-pants, but taking a lot more code

```
FrameList <- mapply(function(FL, i){
                      FL$trial <- i 
                      FL
                    },
                    FrameList, 
                    seq_along(FrameList), 
                    SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Whichever way you go, you can stack them all together with

```
Frame <- do.call("rbind", FrameList)
```

This certainly isn't the most elegant way to do this, so watch for others to give you other clever tricks. But this, I would guess, would be the basic process to follow.